# localStorage.getItem() returns an old value

Tags: javascript, local-storage, save

Local storage has always been working completely fine since I started using it in my project. There have been no real problems with data saving and manipulation. However, recently the `getItem()` method has been returning a random old value. It always returns the same one.

I know this is not an issue with the `setItem()` method because I have looked in devtools and it is writing the correct value. I have tried setting a large `setTimeout` to my save reading function but to no avail. I have spent over an hour on this issue with little progress.

EDIT: Here is the code as requested:

```
// save writing
function generateSave() {
    let oreSave = objMap(oreDict, (i) => {return [!i.discovered, (i.amt * (i.name.charCodeAt(0) - 96))]})
    let itemSave = objMap(itemDict, (i) => {return i.amt * (i.name.charCodeAt(0) - 96)})
    let save = {"ores": oreSave, "money": money, "items": itemSave}
    let encryptedSave = btoa(JSON.stringify(save))
    localStorage.setItem("save", encryptedSave)
}
```

```
function loadSave() {
    let decryptedSave = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem("save")))
    // ...
}
```

Comment: without your code, how can we tell what you are doing wrong?

Comment: @JaromandaX  I have added code. I wrote this at like 10:30pm sorry.

Comment: so `decryptedSave` is always the same (old) value? In other words, it must be the first value stored if it's ALWAYS the same old value

Comment: @JaromandaX It was not the first value stored but rather a more recent save.

Comment: so the issue is that the save fails most of the time - perhaps, `JSON.stringify(save)` doesn't always work

Comment: I have confirmed in devtools that the saving system is working but the loading is not.

Comment: so, you've added a console.log in `function loadSave() {` to verify it is being run at the right time too?